# Azure App Registration - Changing Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been changing some delegated Microsoft Graph permissions in an app registration, but this isn't having any effect on my application. For example, I added the first User.Read and signed into my application and was asked to consent to that (which I did):

[image: MS Graph Permissions]

I then added the User.ReadBasic.All permission and got a message from the portal saying "You are editing permission(s) to your application, users will have to consent even if they’ve already done so previously" which is exactly what I wanted to happen. However, even if I sign out and sign back in again I'm not getting the consent screen again and the call that uses that permission still fails.

I can also remove all the the MS Graph permissions, log out and back in and yet my calls that use User.Read still work and I've waited a few hours just in case it was a caching or timing issue.

Is there a way to force my users to see the new permissions that they have to consent to?

Comment: Did you add new permission to the scope while asking for a token? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#scopes

Comment: Where would i do that? The only scopes I have created are on my API (another app registration) but these changes that I've made are only for MS Graph so nothing to do with the access to my API.

Comment: So in this another app registration you need to add this newly created permission. You can do this in the API permission blade.

Comment: Ok I'll have a look thanks. Still a bit confused as why I'd have to do it in the other app registration though. This app is the web app, the other one is an API. But the web app is just making http calls directly to MS Graph and not via the API.

Comment: Let me know if that was the case :)

Comment: No that's still not working unfortunately. I logged out, added the User.Read and User.ReadBasic.All to the 2nd API registration and I still get the same issues that there is no new consent pop-up and still no permissions to the User.ReadBasic.All methods.

Comment: You didn't describe the flow of the tokens. But in the configuration you set a delegated permission meaning your app needs to run in the context of the user. You must use auth code flow or any other flow to obtain a token in the context of the user.

Comment: Yes I've already got a token back with token_type":"Bearer", and the access_token has my API scope in it. But the API should be irrelevant as the web app is talking directly to MS Graph and I can log in fine and use the original MS Graph permissions, it's just when I change them they aren't being updated.

Comment: I found the problem, you set me off on the right track with mentioning scopes. When I make a http handler in code I specifically define the allowed scopes there but I hadn't added the new scope to the allowed list. Thanks for the help!